# How to use Ampoule with Twisted to create a pool mixed of local and remote processes?

Tags: twisted, multiprocessing, pool

I've been told, that a [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com)-based library [Ampoule](https://launchpad.net/ampoule) is a great way to create a pool of processes that are executed on different computers. However there is no docs for that and Ampoule's examples also don't make it any clear.

I'd be totally happy with interface similar to stdlib multiprocessing.Pool.map()

Could you supply an example, please?

Answer (score 4):

Ampoule is not natively capable of multi-host operation.  Since it uses AMP with strictly defined interactions between the parent and child processes, you could certainly imagine extending it to support multi-host operation.  However, you must still solve the problem of connecting to another host (perhaps via SSH using Twisted Conch) and deploying the necessary Python libraries to it for it to be able to execute the tasks you wish to assign to it.